# Is GNU gprof buggy?

Tags: c, profiling, profiler, gprof

I have a C program that calls a function `pi_calcPiItem()` 600000000 times through the function `pi_calcPiBlock`. So to analyze the time spent in the functions I used GNU gprof. The result seems to be erroneous since all calls are attributed to `main()` instead. Furthermore the call graph does not make any sense:

```
Each sample counts as 0.01 seconds.
  %   cumulative   self              self     total
 time   seconds   seconds    calls  Ts/call  Ts/call  name
 61.29      9.28     9.28                             pi_calcPiItem
 15.85     11.68     2.40                             pi_calcPiBlock
 11.96     13.49     1.81                             _mcount_private
  9.45     14.92     1.43                             __fentry__
  1.45     15.14     0.22                             pow
  0.00     15.14     0.00 600000000     0.00     0.00  main

                        Call graph


granularity: each sample hit covers 4 byte(s) for 0.07% of 15.14 seconds

index % time    self  children    called     name
                                                 <spontaneous>
[1]     61.3    9.28    0.00                 pi_calcPiItem [1]
-----------------------------------------------
                                                 <spontaneous>
[2]     15.9    2.40    0.00                 pi_calcPiBlock [2]
                0.00    0.00 600000000/600000000     main [6]
-----------------------------------------------
                                                 <spontaneous>
[3]     12.0    1.81    0.00                 _mcount_private [3]
-----------------------------------------------
                                                 <spontaneous>
[4]      9.4    1.43    0.00                 __fentry__ [4]
-----------------------------------------------
                                                 <spontaneous>
[5]      1.5    0.22    0.00                 pow [5]
-----------------------------------------------
                                   6             main [6]
                0.00    0.00 600000000/600000000     pi_calcPiBlock [2]
[6]      0.0    0.00    0.00 600000000+6       main [6]
                                   6             main [6]
-----------------------------------------------
```

Is this a bug or do I have to configure the program somehow?

And what does `<spontaneous>` mean?

**EDIT** (more insight for you)

The code is all about the calculation of pi:

```
#define PI_BLOCKSIZE (100000000)
#define PI_BLOCKCOUNT (6)
#define PI_THRESHOLD (PI_BLOCKSIZE * PI_BLOCKCOUNT)

int32_t main(int32_t argc, char* argv[]) {
  double result;

  for ( int32_t i = 0; i < PI_THRESHOLD; i += PI_BLOCKSIZE ) {
    pi_calcPiBlock(&result, i, i + PI_BLOCKSIZE);
  }

  printf("pi = %f\n",result);
  return 0;
}

static void pi_calcPiBlock(double* result, int32_t start, int32_t end) {
  double piItem;

  for ( int32_t i = start; i < end; ++i ) {
    pi_calcPiItem(&piItem, i);
    *result += piItem;
  }  
}    

static void pi_calcPiItem(double* piItem, int32_t index) {
  *piItem = 4.0 * (pow(-1.0,index) / (2.0 * index + 1.0));
}
```

And this is how I got the results (executed on Windows with the help of Cygwin):

```
> gcc -std=c99 -o pi *.c -pg -fno-inline-small-functions
> ./pi.exe
> gprof.exe pi.exe
```

Comment: Code? What command line are you using to look at your results?

Comment: @CDahn I just added what you were asking for.

Comment: Function inlining is a standard C compiler optimization.  You cannot get function call counts for functions that no longer exist.

Comment: @HansPassant Therefore I just used the `-fno-inline-small-functions` parameter to avoid inlining (and, hence, edited the description above). *But*: nothing changed in the output of gprof.

Comment: Double-check your assumptions with -S.  There does get to be a point where tinkering with optimizer settings starts to produce useless profile results.  You're getting well past it by disabling inlining.

Comment: Can you elborate on the `-S` option? I could not find any reference for it. Nevertheless this option leads to a `Bad file number` error when I re-run pi.exe.

Comment: Even if *gprof* did what it claims to do perfectly, it doesn't claim to find ways to speed up your program. If that's what you're expecting, you're gonna be disappointed. [*The problem is, the entire concept is buggy.*](http://archive.today/9r927)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

1. Using the `noinline`, `noclone` function attributes instead of `-fno-inline-small-functions`

   - By disassembling `main` I could see that `-fno-inline-small-functions` doesn't stop inlining
2. Linking your program statically (`-static`)
3. You should also initialize `result` to `0.0` in `main`

This worked for me on Linux, x86-64:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>

#define PI_BLOCKSIZE (100000000)
#define PI_BLOCKCOUNT (6)
#define PI_THRESHOLD (PI_BLOCKSIZE * PI_BLOCKCOUNT)

static void pi_calcPiItem(double* piItem, int32_t index);
static void pi_calcPiBlock(double* result, int32_t start, int32_t end);

int32_t main(int32_t argc, char* argv[]) {
  double result;

  result = 0.0;
  for ( int32_t i = 0; i < PI_THRESHOLD; i += PI_BLOCKSIZE ) {
    pi_calcPiBlock(&result, i, i + PI_BLOCKSIZE);
  }

  printf("pi = %f\n",result);
  return 0;
}

__attribute__((noinline, noclone))
static void pi_calcPiBlock(double* result, int32_t start, int32_t end) {
  double piItem;

  for ( int32_t i = start; i < end; ++i ) {
    pi_calcPiItem(&piItem, i);
    *result += piItem;
  }  
}    

__attribute__((noinline, noclone))
static void pi_calcPiItem(double* piItem, int32_t index) {
  *piItem = 4.0 * (pow(-1.0,index) / (2.0 * index + 1.0));
}
```

**Building the Code**

```
$ cc pi.c -o pi -Os -Wall -g3 -I. -std=c99 -pg -static -lm
```

**Output**

```
$ ./pi && gprof ./pi
pi = 3.141593
Flat profile:

Each sample counts as 0.01 seconds.
  %   cumulative   self              self     total           
 time   seconds   seconds    calls  ns/call  ns/call  name    
 85.61     22.55    22.55                             __ieee754_pow_sse2
  4.75     23.80     1.25                             pow
  4.14     24.89     1.09 600000000     1.82     1.82  pi_calcPiItem
  2.54     25.56     0.67                             __exp1
  0.91     25.80     0.24                             pi_calcPiBlock
  0.53     25.94     0.14                             matherr
  0.47     26.07     0.13                             __lseek_nocancel
  0.38     26.17     0.10                             frame_dummy
  0.34     26.26     0.09                             __ieee754_exp_sse2
  0.32     26.34     0.09                             __profile_frequency
  0.00     26.34     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  main


             Call graph (explanation follows)


granularity: each sample hit covers 2 byte(s) for 0.04% of 26.34 seconds

index % time    self  children    called     name
                                                 <spontaneous>
[1]     85.6   22.55    0.00                 __ieee754_pow_sse2 [1]
-----------------------------------------------
                                                 <spontaneous>
[2]      5.0    0.24    1.09                 pi_calcPiBlock [2]
                1.09    0.00 600000000/600000000     pi_calcPiItem [4]
-----------------------------------------------
                                                 <spontaneous>
[3]      4.7    1.25    0.00                 pow [3]
-----------------------------------------------
                1.09    0.00 600000000/600000000     pi_calcPiBlock [2]
[4]      4.1    1.09    0.00 600000000         pi_calcPiItem [4]
-----------------------------------------------
                                                 <spontaneous>
[5]      2.5    0.67    0.00                 __exp1 [5]
-----------------------------------------------
                                                 <spontaneous>
[6]      0.5    0.14    0.00                 matherr [6]
-----------------------------------------------
                                                 <spontaneous>
[7]      0.5    0.13    0.00                 __lseek_nocancel [7]
-----------------------------------------------
                                                 <spontaneous>
[8]      0.4    0.10    0.00                 frame_dummy [8]
-----------------------------------------------
                                                 <spontaneous>
[9]      0.3    0.09    0.00                 __ieee754_exp_sse2 [9]
-----------------------------------------------
                                                 <spontaneous>
[10]     0.3    0.09    0.00                 __profile_frequency [10]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.00    0.00       1/1           __libc_start_main [827]
[11]     0.0    0.00    0.00       1         main [11]
-----------------------------------------------
```

**Comments**

As expected, `pow()` is the bottleneck. While `pi` is running, `perf top` (sampling based system profiler) also shows `__ieee754_pow_sse2` taking 60%+ of CPU. Changing `pow(-1.0,index)` to `((i & 1) ? -1.0 : 1.0)` as @Mike Dunlavey suggested makes the code roughly 4 times faster.

Comment: Of course, `pow(-1.0, i)` could be reduced to `((i & 1) ? -1.0 : 1.0)`. Should make it a lot faster.

Comment: If you are interested in speed and not too worried about the number of significant digits accuracy, then: 355 / 113 yields a usable result of: 3.14159292,  which I have used in numerous programs where the small error was not important.

Comment: Or...you could just use the M_PI constant from math.h[1], containing as much precision as will fit within a "double" type. If you're going to define your own constant, why would make it less precise than one that already exists? I think the point of this program is to calculate pi though, not to use pi.

[1]http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/math.h.html

Answer (score 0):

In 'man gprof' page, here is explanation for "spontaneous":

> Parents that are not themselves profiled will have the time of
>   their profiled children propagated to them, but they will appear to be
>   spontaneously invoked in the call graph listing, and will not have
>   their time propagated further.  Similarly, signal catchers, even
>   though profiled, will appear to be    spontaneous (although for more
>   obscure reasons).  Any profiled children of signal catchers should
>   have their times propagated properly, unless the signal catcher was
>   invoked during the execution of the profiling routine, in which case
>   all is lost.